# Looking for algorithm: Clustering by 'similarity'

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis

I have a set of 'vectors' and i need to sort them basing on their 'similarity'.

Like this: vectors {1,0,0} {1,1,0} {0,1,0} {1,0,1} are pretty similiar and should be close to each other in the end, but vectors {1, 0, 0} {8, 0, 0} {0, 5, 0} - are not.

The metric between A and B is max(abs(A[i]-B[i])), but what kind of algorithms can sort things basing on relative comparison?

upd:
input: array of N vectors
ouput: array of N vectors, where nearest by index vectors(arr[i] arr[i+1] for example) are 'similiar' = metric between arr[i] and arr[i+1] is as low as possibly for any i, j.
metric - maximum difference of vector components

upd2:
as it seems now, @jogojapan was right - i need to cluster vectors and after, print them in some linear order, group by group

Comment: define what do you mean by 'sort'...  do you have a metric? do you want to minimize the sum of the distances between adjacent vectors?

Comment: Perhaps you mean [clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) (i.e. grouping), rather than sorting?

Comment: let me rephrase my comment: if you have two orderings how can you decide which one is better? "should be close to each" is not a definition...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath yah, i was wrong, by calling it "sorting". Seems clustering is what i need here

Comment: are you sure? do you want to separate the vectors into distinct *sets*?

Comment: Your vectors appear to be triples.  Do these roughly equate to cartesian axes (x,y,z), and by similarity do you hence mean cartesian distance?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath not sure, but i think that separating the vectors into distinct sets and then reordering this sets in some linear order may work, need to try it

Comment: @ShaneMacLaughlin no, 'triples' - just for example, in the task vectors have greater dimension

Answer (score 3):

That's a distance induced by [max norm (aka sup norm or l-infinity norm)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space). A distance is not enough to create a linear ordering, if by sorting you mean ordring in a sequence.

Comment: There is no reason why you couldn't order by distance from the origin.

Comment: @Marcin possible. But I doubt that's what user286215 wants. He said 'relative comparison'.

Answer (score 2):

Sorting is inherently a one-dimensional problem.  What you're describing here sounds more like a weighted graph but it's not clear what your goal is.  You may also find some concepts from information theory such as [Hamming Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) to be useful if you're trying to identify the vector which is "closest" to a known vector.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the obvious approach would be the (IMHO badly named) "hierarchical clustering", which always merges those clusters with the smallest distance. You can plug in your metric there. Most implementations are in O(n^3) and thus not useful for large datasets. Plus, you get a huge dendrogram that is hard to read.

You might want to give OPTICS a try. Look it up on Wikipedia. It might satisfy your needs quite well, since it in fact *sorts* the points. It will walk from one cluster to another, and can in fact produce a hierarchical (as in "nested") clustering. A good implementation should run in O(n^2) without index structures and in O(n log n) with index acceleration.

Answer (score -1):

Any sorting algorithm can give you the results you want.

The question is how you are going to compare your vectors. Do you just want to compare them by magnitude? Or something else?

Comment: that is the problem, i can not compare vectors, but for any given pair  i can tell how 'similiar' are they

Comment: @user286215 So, you have no problem. As long as you can test whether they are greater, lesser, or equal, any sorting algorithm will work.

Comment: "As long as you can test whether they are greater, lesser, or equal" - well, that's the definition of comparison. he just said he cannot compare them.. or from an other perspective: if he compares them then he definitely won't reach his goal.

Comment: @Karoly Horvat hunfortunately it does not work (i tried) - it does not group similar vectors together

Comment: @user286215: I know.. see my comments for your question.